# How can I remove compiled kernel?

Tags: kernel, software-uninstall

I installed 14.10 on my laptop Lenovo E455.

And compiled kernel 3.19 with following order

since it seemed that 14.10 doesn't want to work with mine.(I saw slow motions)

Downloaded current kernel from http://www.kernel.org/

```
make oldconfig
make
sudo make install
```

Finally, failed to boot with new kernel.

How can I remove the compiled kernel from grub and get recovered?

Comment: What did you try so far to remove it and where did it go wrong? Where there any warning or error messages?

Comment: Thanks to your help. Got recovered and waiting for Ubuntu 15.XX.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If compiled and installed via `make install`, you will need to manually remove the following entries:

```
/boot/vmlinuz*KERNEL-VERSION*
/boot/initrd*KERNEL-VERSION*
/boot/System-map*KERNEL-VERSION*
/boot/config-*KERNEL-VERSION*
/lib/modules/*KERNEL-VERSION*/
/var/lib/initramfs/*KERNEL-VERSION*/
```

Then update the grub configuration:

```
sudo update-grub2
```

If compiled via the `debian method`, you can see the installed `kernel` with the following:

`dpkg --list | grep kernel-image`

And then uninstall the desired kernel package with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get remove kernel-image-your-kernel-image
```

**Reference:**

- [Compile Linux Kernel on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Detailed)](https://mitchtech.net/compile-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-detailed/): This answer draws *heavily* from this post and the comments attached to it.

Comment: I do not have /var/lib/initramfs/ directory, but is it because I do not have compiled kernels in my system?

Comment: `/var/lib/initramfs-tools/*KERNEL-VERSION*` on Debian

Comment: Consider an edit for newer kernels (year 2018) containing: `/boot/abi*KERNEL-VERSION*` and `/boot/retpoline*KERNEL-VERSION*`

Comment: This is a joke. Actually, i'm not surprised.

Answer (score 14):

Thanks to jarno's question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/779031/how-to-remove-kernels-from-previous-release) I worked out a way of implementing Mudit Kapil's answer that requires very little typing and catches any extra bits lying around

Since all that is needed to remove the kernel is to delete all its files & directories, and all those files and directories will have the kernel release string in their paths, we can use `locate` to find all the files with the kernel release string and delete them to remove the kernel.

**(First check `uname -r` to find the name of the currently running kernel & be sure not to delete it)**

Say you want to remove a kernel called `4.4.6-my-kernel`. You can find all its existing files & directories (without listing the files in all the named directories) with `locate -b -e 4.4.6-my-kernel`. Appending `rm -r` to this with `xargs` allows you to delete the files too. I add `-p` to make `xargs` display targets and ask for confirmation before executing

```
locate -b -e 4.4.6-my-kernel | xargs -p sudo rm -r
```

then type `y` to execute `rm -r` on the targets shown. It will complain that files that are not directories don't exist because you're trying to delete them recursively (`-r`) but that's OK, they will still be removed along with the directories and their contents. When done, just run

```
sudo update-grub
```

et voila.

Comment: +1 because this catches more files than accepted answer. For example all the `dkms` stuff. I would run it first without the `rm` option just to see everything that would be deleted.

Comment: Why shouldn't I delete the currently running kernel? What if that is the kernel I want to delete? Is it possible to delete the currently running kernel without first restarting the machine with another kernel?

Comment: @LiranFunaro it is possible yes. See my answer [How do I uninstall the running kernel by command only?](//askubuntu.com/a/1091529) which also explains why it is probably not a good idea