# Where does update-initramfs look for kernel versions?

Tags: kernel, filesystem, initramfs

I needed to regenerate initrd. Doing this:

```
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

threw up errors for a kernel I compiled and then deleted some time ago (because `update-initramfs` could not find the `/lib/modules` directory I had deleted of course).

I thought I had completely removed the kernel by deleting all its entries in `/boot` and directory in `/lib/modules` & running `sudo update-grub` (as in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/594484/527764)), but apparently there are traces of it somewhere that I should probably clean up.

I read [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Initramfs) and dug around in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools` but I couldn't figure it out.

In `man update-initramfs` I see that:

> The use of "all" for the version string specifies update-initramfs to execute the chosen action for all kernel versions, that are already known to update-initramfs.

But how does it know them? Where does `update-initramfs` look for kernel versions?

Note: many months later... I added the answer to this question to the tag wiki for [initramfs](/questions/tagged/initramfs)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, I also thought I had completely removed the kernel by deleting all its entries in `/boot` and directory in `/lib/modules` & updating GRUB, but I found the one directory that is used by `update-initramfs` to keep track of the kernels:

```
/var/lib/initramfs-tools
```

Comment: `update-initramfs -d -k <version>` will remove the entry in `/var/lib/initramfs-tools` and the image in `/boot` in one go, just fyi:)