# Errors were encountered while processing: initramfs-tools linux-image-5.4.0-47-generic linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic

Tags: boot, apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

Kubuntu 20.04: `/boot` disk size is 500MB, but only 7MB free. When I try to do repair from boot menu, it says I need to free space up.

tried with

1. `sudo apt-get upgrade`
2. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
3. `sudo apt-get update`
4. `sudo apt-get autoremove`
5. `sudo apt-get clean`
6. `sudo apt-get install --fix-broken`
7. `sudo apt-get install -f`
8. `sudo apt-get remove ––purge package_name`
9. `sudo apt-get auto-remove && apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

I always get:

```
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.3) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-47-generic (5.4.0-47.51) ...
I: /boot/initrd.img.old is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.4.0-47-generic
Setting up linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic (5.4.0-48.52) ...
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sdb2
I: (UUID=667e1f29-5952-421e-b068-dc53873735bc)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-47-generic (5.4.0-47.51) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-47-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-47-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sdb2
I: (UUID=667e1f29-5952-421e-b068-dc53873735bc)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-47-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-47-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-47-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic (5.4.0-48.52) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms:
 * dkms: running auto installation service for kernel 5.4.0-48-generic
   ...done.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sdb2
I: (UUID=667e1f29-5952-421e-b068-dc53873735bc)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-48-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
 linux-image-5.4.0-47-generic
 linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic
```

I also  tried with:

```
sudo apt purge linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic
sudo apt purge linux-image-5.4.0-47-generic
```

because I have them both in boot disk, but I get:

```
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-5.4.0-48-generic (5.4.0-48.52) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.136ubuntu6.3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sdb2
I: (UUID=667e1f29-5952-421e-b068-dc53873735bc)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block 
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 lz4 -9 -l 24
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-45-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Give this solution a try to free up space in boot: https://askubuntu.com/questions/827114/what-to-do-about-update-initramfs-errors-during-kernel-upgrade

Comment: 500 MB ??? You sure it's not GB? Find out what fills your HD and remove the files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error 24 : Write error : cannot write compressed block](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207958/error-24-write-error-cannot-write-compressed-block)