# How to remove a kernel from ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, kernel, dpkg

I'm using Ubuntu along side windows in dual boot. I downloaded, compiled and booted linux-stable kernel from Linux's official repository.
Now I want to remove this kernel, I tried searching online.

But when i use `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`, I couldn't find linux-stable kernel which i downloaded, So I couldn't follow online guide.

```
srivathsa@srivathsa:~$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-5.11.0-25-generic              5.11.0-25.27~20.04.1                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic               5.8.0-43.49~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-50-generic               5.8.0-50.56~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic               5.8.0-53.60~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.8.0-59-generic               5.8.0-59.66~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04              5.11.0.25.27~20.04.10                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

where as kernel which i downloaded was 5.12.17.

So, how should I remove this kernel?

contents of boot:

```
srivathsa@srivathsa:~$ ls /boot/
config-5.11.0-25-generic  initrd.img-5.11.0-25-generic  memtest86+_multiboot.bin      vmlinuz-5.12.17
config-5.12.17            initrd.img-5.12.17            System.map-5.11.0-25-generic  vmlinuz-5.8.0-53-generic
config-5.8.0-53-generic   initrd.img-5.8.0-53-generic   System.map-5.12.17            vmlinuz-5.8.0-59-generic
config-5.8.0-59-generic   initrd.img-5.8.0-59-generic   System.map-5.8.0-53-generic   vmlinuz.old
efi                       initrd.img.old                System.map-5.8.0-59-generic
grub                      memtest86+.bin                vmlinuz
initrd.img                memtest86+.elf                vmlinuz-5.11.0-25-generic
```

Comment: [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/594484/1222991) should give you what you need 

Comment: Thanks it helped!